# Force MPMoviePlayerController to play in landscape

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm new to iPhone Development and writing my first App. The whole App only needs portrait mode, except for playing movies. I am using MPMoviePlayerController to start the movie and it plays in protrait mode. How can I force MPMoviePlayerController to play all movies in Landscape.
I am using Xcode 4 and building for iOS 4.0+. Do I need to enter some settings in the info.plist to allow MPMoviePlayerController to play in landscape?

Here is the code I use to initialize MPMoviePlayerController:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url]; 
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
theMovie.allowsAirPlay=YES;
[theMovie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
[theMovie play];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embed the player in it's own view controller and implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: this isn't working for me - i have a view controller which presents the movies, and its entirely in landscape mode, but the movie still launches in portrait... ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a sub class of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`:

`@interface MyMoviePlayerViewController ()`

`@end`

```
@implementation MyMoviePlayerViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate { return NO; }
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

@end
```